# Skype or Zoom without mouse

Tags: skype, zoom-sdk

I am trying to set up a simple video-call device for a senior that has absolutely no idea of technology.

The plan:

An old Laptop connected to a monitor and a USB keypad. The laptop boots up (win 7 or 10) and starts skype or zoom ( some form of Kiosk). The senior can only accept a call with on big green button. The senior can call people with a push of a button.

The Problem:

I could not find any way to make a call (zoom or skype... this would be widely accepted from other not very tech-friendly relatives) with just a key combination/ shortcut that does not include a mouse.

The solution so far (not the road I want to continue):
I made a video call device with a pi, an old monitor, just one button, and a jitsi-meet (browser)
my current setup does not enable the senior in question to actively make calls and is generally too unreliable

I am looking forward to someone pointing me in the right direction

Comment: Touch screen? You can find 2nd hand.

Comment: hack a USB keyboard into a controller with a few buttons

Comment: use an arduino leonardo as a USB mouse/keyboard ... a button press could result in a mouse click at a specific place on the screen

Comment: thank you. Touch screen seemed like a real good idea but skype or zoom or teams or... are still to complicated. for a senior. If the mouse click is always in the same position i would not be able to call different people. I need a way to press "button x" on a USB keypad and that would trigger the call of a specific person. I cant find the interface. there is no combination of keys that makes a call...